# django redirecting an ajax request but keeping it an "is_ajax"

Tags: python, ajax, django, redirect

the question: How do i redirect to a page in django but "fake" it as an ajax request?

So i have a post data request - done via ajax (jQuery). This gets sent to my django server, which adds the data (or removes it!) and then responds with a "well done you added some data" page.

This success page begins with:

```
{% extends request.is_ajax|yesno:"base_ajax.htm,base.htm" %}
```

which is a nice way of adding in all sorts of headers if the request wasn't an ajax one, and ignoring the headers if it was. I added this so the site works both with and without javascript (do we need to do that anymore?)

And then i added a post-redirect-get (that is, the post part of the view doesn't `return render_to_response` but rather `return redirect('url here')`

And now the problem is that the redirect forgets that the initial request was an ajax one. So i always end up loading the entire page - headers and all - into a div, which isn't what i want.

So, i'd like to be able to *tell the redirect that it should pretend  to be an ajax request*

How do i do that?

UPDATE: to anybody reading this in "the future (with jetpacks!)" redirects don't carry the header information over - see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-7.1

in the end, i went and did this:

```
return redirect(self.success_redirect + '/' + str(int(request.is_ajax())))
```

and then, for the view that i redirected to i had:

```
url(r'^editStorySuccess/(?P<ajax>\d+)$',
    showAfterCheckingAjax,
    {
        'template':'stories/editStorySuccess.html'
    },
    'editStorySuccess'
),
```

and in the showAfterCheckingAjax view i just had:

```
if int(ajax):
    request.META['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'
return render_to_response(template, {'user':request.user}, 
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and that works for me!

Comment: an ajax request is just a normal http request, plus whatever extra headers browsers insert to tag it as ajax. there's no fundamental difference. add those headers, and boom, it's "ajax".

Comment: If you're going to use Ajax to submit your data, using the PRG pattern is not that very useful, so you might want return the actual response and not a redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a different URL that presents the same view as the URL you're redirecting to now but with an additional GET parameter. You can use this GET parameter to modify the template that is being used to serve the view. Either way, a redirect is considered a new request so you have to do something to pass this additional information to this request.

Answer (score 1):

Get the redirect url as a json data from the call back method of the request and then redirect from the page using JavaScript.

Comment: that is a *very* particular way to do it. That means that my jQuery code is now, in some cases, checking the response from its requests and calling a redirect on that?? This seems a very verbose way of doing things... django offers no such facility itself?

Comment: +1 particular and not the way i did it, but a solution nonetheless. Might even involve less code!

Comment: actually, i think this i wrong. i don't think it is possible to "catch" a redirect in process in jQuery...

Comment: @bharal You are not getting it.You need to send the url as a JSON data and then parse it using JS/JQuery

Comment: ? so the jQuery posts data off, and receives some json back, and then from there launches a redirect, depending on the contents of the  json?